# Trigger Redis HMSET with LUA

Tags: node.js, lua, redis

I have need to call Redis HMSET with a Redis Lua script. Here is a coffee script:

```
redis = require("redis")
client = redis.createClient();

lua_script = "\n
-- here is the problem\n
local res = redis.call('hmset', KEYS[1],ARGV[1])\n
print (res)\n
-- create secondary indexes\n
--\n
--\n
return 'Success'\n
"

client.on 'ready', () ->
  console.log 'Redis is ready'
  client.flushall()
  client.send_command("script", ["flush"])

  args = new Array(3)

  args[0] = '1111-1114'
  args[1] = 'id'
  args[2] = '111'
  callback = null
  #client.send_command("hmset", args, callback) # this works

  client.eval lua_script, 1, args, (err, res) ->
    console.log 'Result: ' + res
```

What is the correct syntax / pattern to call HMSET in the LUA script?
BTW - I am aware of the redis.HMSET command.

Comment: I'm new to using lua in redis, but you may need to use `unpack`. I use it the code I've posted [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30195/redis-rate-limiting-in-lua), though I use it for `HMGET`.

Comment: BTW It's 'Lua' not 'LUA'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, are you sure you are using `eval` in your CoffeeScript Redis library correctly? You are apparently passing three arguments: the script, the number of keys and an array. I suspect this is not how it works. If this is node_redis, either everything or nothing must be in the array, so try:

```
args = new Array(5)

args[0] = lua_script
args[1] = 1
args[2] = '1111-1114'
args[3] = 'id'
args[4] = '111'
callback = null

client.eval args, (err, res) ->
  console.log 'Result: ' + res
```

(There is probably a nicer syntax but I don't know CoffeeScript.)

Secondly, in this example you are trying to HMSET a single field/value pair:

```
HMSET lua_script 1111-1114 id 111
```

Actually you could replace HMSET by HSET here, but let's make it work first.

In this line:

```
local res = redis.call('hmset', KEYS[1], ARGV[1])
```

You are only calling HMSET with *two* arguments, the key containing the hash and the field. You need to add the value which is the second argument:

```
local res = redis.call('hmset', KEYS[1], ARGV[1], ARGV[2])
```

This will make your example work, but what if you want to actually set *multiple* fields (which is the goal of MHSET) like so?

```
HMSET lua_script 1111-1114 id 111 id2 222
```

In CoffeeScript you would write:

```
args = new Array(7)

args[0] = lua_script
args[1] = 1
args[2] = '1111-1114'
args[3] = 'id'
args[4] = '111'
args[5] = 'id2'
args[6] = '222'
callback = null

client.eval args, (err, res) ->
  console.log 'Result: ' + res
```

... but now you have *four* elements in `ARGV` to pass to `redis.call` in Lua. Actually you have to pass *all* the elements of `ARGV`, and this is called [unpack()](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-unpack) in Lua:

```
local res = redis.call('hmset', KEYS[1], unpack(ARGV))
```

The only issue with using `unpack()` is that if you have a *real* lot of elements in `ARGV` (thousands) it can break because it will overflow the stack, in which case you should use a loop in the Lua script to call HMSET on slices of `ARGV`, but you should probably not worry about that for now...